# How to generate .class files?

Tags: java, android, class

I am trying to find .class files in an android Studio project. Is there a way to generate the .class files using android studio?

Comment: your project class files?

Comment: I mean the (.class) files that are generated after compiling java class(.java) @NoumanCh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes are located in your app -> build -> intermediates -> classes -> <build config> -> <package name>

Answer (score 1):

In the Android studio, there is a very simple way to do it. Go to "find everywhere" (short cut ctrl + shift + F) and filter by *.class, look at the image above:

[image]

Comment: - Thanks for replaying, I find .class files of some project. How can I generate files of other projects?

Comment: @N.IT I recommend to you better ask a new question, so the issues can go separate ways, and not mix different subjects in the same question